# Facebook friends picture/brithday etc names are ok

Tags: php, facebook, json, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following which is working perfectly to display friends' names

```
$access_token = "___access-token___";
$friendsList = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=".$access_token),true) ;
$data = $friendsList['data'] ;

foreach ($data as $nr => $friends)
{
 echo $friends['name'].'<br /><br />';  // line AAA     
}
```

But if try change line AAA to e.g. $friends['birthday'] or $friends['picture'] I get nothing??  Any ideas?

BTW, RE birthday, I have friends_birthday in scope to allow this info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define wanted fields directly in the request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends/?fields=birthday,picture
```

If you are allowed to see the friend's birthday - it will be in the result row

Answer (score 0):

Friend only contains name and id, you have to link it to the user table to get the birthday of your friend by using the friend id.

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends
will return list of friends with id-name only.

if you want basic profile for each friend
- call https://graph.facebook.com/friend_user_id

to get extended profile
call https://graph.facebook.com/friend_user_id?access_token=append_valid_access_token

if you want much more extensive profile details, you will need to have necessary permissions
see; https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

to be able to get extended profile information, you